# Why does a cc file defining a map with 1500 elements need to be compiled for ten seconds

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, clang, clang++

```
// a.cc
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

std::unordered_map<int32_t, std::vector<int32_t>> kItemAdDspInfoCommonAttr = {
  {1, {30740}},
  ...1500....
};
```

A cc file like the above needs to be compiled for 10s. As the key-value pairs of the map increase, the compilation time will swell even more.

[image]
Through the information printed by ftime-trace, I found that the time-consuming is mainly the [sroa](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/1603#:%7E:text=The%20next%20pass,into%20its%20components) pass. I found that this is aggregate alloca.

Comment: What exactly is not clear about compilation time having linear correlation with the code length? If you are using GNU Make you may pass -j<n_of_cpu_cores> i.e. `make -j4` to compile faster.

Comment: Snarky answer: because the compiler spends ten seconds generating and optimizing code for all the `initializer_list`s and invocations of `std::vector::vector`. Isolate this large data structure in a separate file to reduce the number of times you recompile it.